Difference between output of two queries in SumoLogic
I need to find out the difference between values returned by two different queries
Query 1
(_sourceCategory="{{_sourceCategory}}")
| where  (_sourcename matches "a-*-base-*" and environment = "{{environment}}" and locationinfo.rootcontainer matches "*-main" and !(locationinfo.rootcontainer matches "a-*-main")) | count(locationinfo.rootcontainer), pct(elapsed,90,95,99), avg(elapsed), min(elapsed), max(elapsed) group by locationinfo.rootcontainer | sort by locationinfo.rootcontainer asc

Query 2
(_sourceCategory="{{_sourceCategory}}")
| where  (environment = "{{environment}}" and tracePoint matches "OUTBOUND_REQUEST_SCOPE_AFTER" and _sourcename matches "a-*-top-*") | count(locationinfo.rootcontainer),pct(elapsed,90,95,99), avg(elapsed) , min(elapsed), max(elapsed) group by locationinfo.rootcontainer | sort by locationinfo.rootcontainer asc

I need to take the difference between Query 1.pct(elapsed) and Query 2.pct(elapsed)
However I need both queries to be part of the same log query. Any idea how this could be achieved?
I tried Sumologic: calculate a value from two log queries for inspiration
(_sourceCategory="{{_sourceCategory}}")
| if ((_sourcename matches "sf-mer-*-eapi-*" and environment = "{{environment}}" and locationinfo.rootcontainer matches "*-main" and !(locationinfo.rootcontainer matches "sf-mer-*-main")),1,0) as query1
| if ( (environment = "{{environment}}" and tracePoint matches "OUTBOUND_REQUEST_SCOPE_AFTER" and _sourcename matches "sf-mer-*-papi-*"),1,0) as query2
| count(query1.locationinfo.rootcontainer) - count(query2.locationinfo.rootcontainer) group by query1.locationinfo.rootcontainer | sort by query1.locationinfo.rootcontainer asc

I got an error however:
Error while parsing: Unexpected token '-' found. Parsed [(_sourceCategory="nonprod/cloudhub/muleapps/logs") | if ((_sourcename matches "a-*-base-*" and environment = "qa" and locationinfo.rootcontainer matches "*-main" and !(locationinfo.rootcontainer matches "a-*-main")),1,0) as query1 | if ( (environment = "qa" and tracePoint matches "OUTBOUND_REQUEST_SCOPE_AFTER" and _sourcename matches "a-*-top-*"),1,0) as query2 | count(query1.locationinfo.rootcontainer) ], error at [- count(query2.locationinfo.rootcontainer) group by query1.locationinfo.rootcontainer | sort by query1.locationinfo.rootcontainer asc]

P.S. - I am a rank beginner on SumoLogic
